# How to retrieve csv data stored in a 'text' field into another table in postgresql?

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

For example

[image]

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `string_to_array` to divide to rows by carriage return and then split by `|` char, eg:

```
t=# with a("Data") as (values('a|b|c'||chr(10)||'d|e|f'))
, mid as (select unnest(string_to_array("Data",chr(10))) u from a)
select split_part(u,'|',1) x, split_part(u,'|',2) y, split_part(u,'|',3) z from mid;
 x | y | z
---+---+---
 a | b | c
 d | e | f
(2 rows)
```

Comment: you are great . Its working . Thank you for you great help

Comment: Can we achieve the same with a pair of regexp_split_to_table functions? If yes,which one is better for huge data? Could you share query with regexp_split_to_table function if it is possible?